# syntax error, unexpected || in instance_eval string

Tags: ruby

I want to interpolate a value in an `instance_eval` string. the argument `alias_name` can sometimes be nil or a string. If it is nil, then I invoke another method which returns a string, as shown below:

```
def create_document(klass, alias_name)
  klass.instance_eval <<-EOS
      def alias_name
        #{alias_name} || name
      end
  EOS
end
```

But this is actually giving me a syntax error:

```
Uncaught exception: (eval):2: syntax error, unexpected ||
         || name
           ^
```

I am looking closely at this code and I don't see the syntax error. If `#{alias_name}` is either returning nil or string, why would this cause an error?

After all this all works:

```
> nil || 'something else'
 => "something else" 
> 'something' || 'something else'
 => "something"
```

When `alias_name` is nil, it doesn't get evaluated at all. Its like just nonexistant in the instance_eval string, causing syntax error. But even this does not work:

```
alias_name = alias_name || ""
klass.instance_eval <<-EOS
  def alias_name
    if #{alias_name}.present?
      #{alias_name}
    else
      demodulized_name
    end
  end
EOS
```

It would give this error:

```
Uncaught exception: (eval):2: syntax error, unexpected '.'
        if .present?
            ^
```

You see that? Its as if `alias_name` does not exist.

Comment: It's issues like this that make `eval` a tricky and potentially very dangerous tool. Whenever possible try and do this with the `define_method` system and things like `send(alias_name)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using string interpolation, `"s #{expr} s"` is equivalent to:

```
's ' + expr.to_s + ' s'
```

and `nil.to_s` is an empty string so this:

```
klass.instance_eval <<-EOS
  def alias_name
    #{alias_name} || name
  end
EOS
```

ends up like:

```
klass.instance_eval %q{
  def alias_name
    || name
  end
}
```

when `alias_name` is `nil` or an empty string and:

```
def alias_name
  || name
end
```

is not syntactically correct Ruby code.

The heredoc that you're feeding to `klass.instance_eval` doesn't know that there's any special "this is Ruby code" context, it is just building a string like any other string and blindly call `to_s` on the `#{}` interpolations.

Perhaps you want to use `inspect` instead of `to_s`:

```
klass.instance_eval <<-EOS
  def alias_name
    #{alias_name.inspect} || name
  end
EOS
```

That will give you Ruby code like:

```
def alias_name
  nil || name
end
```

when `alias_name` is `nil` and:

```
def alias_name
  "pancakes" || name
end
```

when `alias_name` is the string `'pancakes'`.

Or perhaps you want the test outside the `instance_eval` if `alias_name` is meant to be the name of another method:

```
if alias_name.present?
  klass.instance_eval <<-EOS
    def alias_name
      #{alias_name} || name
    end
  EOS
else
  klass.instance_eval <<-EOS
    def alias_name
      name
    end
  EOS
end
```

Comment: Interesting, I never really understood the difference of to_s and inspect until this.